# Finding Nuget Package Documentation

Tags: sql, nuget

I can't find any usage documentation for some Nuget packages.

I did a google search and searched Nuget.

Install-Package SQLSelect.QueryBuilder -Version 1.0.0

Install-Package Newq

I'm trying to find documentation for the Nuget packages above. I want to make a program that has an Access Like query builder and I wanted to look at these two packages.

I have no ideas how to use them, I don't see any examples or documentation with them.

Does anybody know of any documentation for either of them?

Is there a better sql builder for net that is free?

Answer (score 1):

The first port of call is usually the NuGet Gallery pages, e.g.:

- [SQLSelect.QueryBuilder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLSelect.QueryBuilder/)
- [Newq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newq/)

  - This also reveals a link to their [Project Site](https://github.com/apemost/Newq) on GitHub, so you can at least browse their source code to see how it works.

In the Info panel at the top right of each page is a `Contact Owners` link that should at least enable you to ask the package owners for more information. It's unfortunate that they don't supply any documentation links.

Without more context about what it is you're trying to do, though, I can't provide you further guidance on the rest of your question... "what is better?" is considered to be an opinionated question and you haven't listed any requirements as to what functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see about contacting the owners. I'm looking for  an Access Like query builder that will work with access or sql databases in a c# application.